# Двоеточие в сложном бессоюзном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли здесь стоит двоеточие? Изначально было тире, но мне кажется, оно здесь может быть разве что интонационным...

ООО «...» не стоит на месте: коллектив предприятия растет и пополняется молодыми специалистами, которые готовы продолжать улучшать качество производимой продукции, внедряя новые технологии производства, заключаются новые договора с российскими поставщиками комплектующих, отливок и металлосортамента, ведется строгий выходной контроль качества комплектующих и внутренний контроль на каждом этапе производства продукции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Двоеточие здесь стоит на месте, а вот в самом тексте слово "договора" я изменил бы на "договоры", хотя форма "договора" допустима, но не очень желательна

Answer (score 1):

Помимо двоеточия (оно нужно, если решено объединить всё в одну фразу), здесь ощущается потребность в дополнительной пунктуации. Восприятие перечисляемого усложнено присутствием в первом случае подчинённого предложения и связанного с ним деепричастного оборота. Вероятно, эту часть (для обозначения её окончания) лучше отделить не запятой, а точкой с запятой (после "производства"). Это касается и следующей части, внутри которой есть перечисление через запятую (точку с запятой можно поставить после "металлосортамента"). "Ведутся" - лучше множественное число для смыслового объединения двух "контролей".

"Комплектующие" - сокращённое понятие, которым обмениваются в процессе работы (это не совсем "мороженое" или "заливное"); в материале, предназначенном для широкого прочтения, лучше написать полностью: "комплектующих изделий" (аналогично, напр. "слизистая *оболочка*" - за пределами мед. учреждения; сокращённое "при отягчающих" или "на морально-волевых" - тоже недоговорки из узкопрофессиональной практики :) ).